# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Tags: ios, xcode

OMG - 4 Hours and still going crazy.

I have xcode set for iOS Device.
I removed all my certificates and added new ones...

AHHHHH, please help...

Validate "/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tap_App_Sports_Timer-adjocqnzdvhhsffcihaybibvneji/ArchiveIntermediates/Tap App Sports Timer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Hockey Player Timer.app"
    cd "/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Projects/Tap App Sports Timer"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/jmchattie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tap_App_Sports_Timer-adjocqnzdvhhsffcihaybibvneji/ArchiveIntermediates/Tap App Sports Timer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Hockey Player Timer.app"

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tap_App_Sports_Timer-adjocqnzdvhhsffcihaybibvneji/ArchiveIntermediates/Tap App Sports Timer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Hockey Player Timer.app/Hockey Player Timer
codesign_wrapper-0.7.5: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: keychain-access-groups, {type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (
    0 : {contents = "8AV8Q354Q5.ca.elbacil-ppa"}
)}
 - (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Solved....

It seems one only needs an Entitlements.plist when submitting an App for AD HOC DISTRIBUTION

Entitlements.plist is not necessary for AppStore

Crap, 4 hours I will never get back.

J